# How to get iframe ID from below DOM using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to access iframe Id from below DOM using jquery.

```
<div>
  <a href="#" id="0" class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">Read Less</a>
  <div class="Description" style="">
    <iframe src="/temp.php" scrolling="no" id="1111111"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically when you click on link , it will show the DIV with class `Description` . So i want to get iframe ID within that current div

--Update--

Thanks for your answers. However, when i pass this value to next function which rsizes the iframe gets undefined value

```
$(".Description").hide();
$('a.show_hide').on("click", function () {
var txt = $(this).next('.Description').is(':visible')? 'Read More' : 'Read Less';
                $(this).text(txt);

        $(this).next('.Description').slideToggle(200);
  var i=$(this).next('.Description').find('iframe').attr('id');
  resizeThisIframe(i);
});


function resizeThisIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
```

Look at jsfiddle demo

https://jsfiddle.net/1rnwapse/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
$('.show_hide').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).next(".Description").find("iframe").attr("id"))
});
```

**demo**

```js
$('.show_hide').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).next(".Description").find("iframe").attr("id"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="#" id="0" class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">Read Less</a>
  <div class="Description" style=""><iframe src="/temp.php" scrolling="no" id="1111111"></iframe></div>
</div>
<div><a href="#" id="0" class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">Read Less</a>
  <div class="Description" style=""><iframe src="/temp.php" scrolling="no" id="222222"></iframe></div>
</div>
<div><a href="#" id="0" class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">Read Less</a>
  <div class="Description" style=""><iframe src="/temp.php" scrolling="no" id="333333"></iframe></div>
</div>
<div><a href="#" id="0" class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">Read Less</a>
  <div class="Description" style=""><iframe src="/temp.php" scrolling="no" id="4444444"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already tried this but for some reason, its showing me undefined value

Comment: Can't tell you why your returned undefined if you used this exact code

Comment: Thanks, i am able to retrieve it now but see my updated question

Comment: @EverythingEthical Try and look at the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1rnwapse/15/   It looks like you are sending the id but in your `resizeThisIframe` function you are expecting an object

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use DOM traversal in the click handler of the `a`:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).next('.Description').find('iframe').prop('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$('a.show_hide').click(function() {
  let id = $(this).next('.Description').find('iframe').attr('id');
  alert(id);
});
```

onclick of anchor tag, traverse through DOM and get ifrmae ID.